# hreflang for URL which can show the content in more than one language

Tags: hreflang

I wonder if it's correct for a URL which shows the content in English or Spanish depending on the browser language setting, to use these tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="es" />
```